# How to select randomly a pairs of adjacent elements from a python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, element

What is the best way to select randomly two adjacent elements from a list?

As  for example, for a given list `M=[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]`
Suppose I would like to select elements like `(2,0),(6,5),(89,12),(5,89),(0,8)` etc.
Here is the code I have tried :

```
import random
D=[]
M=[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]
  for r in range(10):
  D.append((random.sample(M,2)))
```

But it does not give the right pairs

Comment: D.append will work.. A typo I think

Comment: Try printing D it will give you the random pairs. What do you mean by correct pairs?

Comment: D.append is working for me but it does not give the correct result which I want. Please see my question@Ashutosh Chapagain

Comment: I would like to select any two consecutive elements  randomly from a list@Ashutosh Chapagain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the length of the list as a limit for a random integer then use it as an index into the list, also select the next item.

```
>>> a =[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]
>>> n_pairs = 6
>>> for _ in range(n_pairs):
...     i = random.randrange(len(a)-1)
...     print(a[i], a[i+1])

6 5
89 12
5 89
2 4
5 6
12 23

>>>
```

---

Without repeats:

```
>>> a =[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]
>>> n_pairs = 6
>>> if n_pairs > len(a)//2:
    raise ValueError

>>> indices = random.sample(range(len(a)), n_pairs)
>>> result = [(a[i], a[i+1]) for i in indices]
>>> result
[(2, 0), (0, 8), (6, 5), (6, 5), (5, 89), (89, 12)]
```

Comment: This gives the wrong selection. There is no pars like  (4,2), (0,4)@wwii

Comment: Thnx @DavisHerring !!

Comment: This is will also give you repeated pairs.

Comment: @mamun: Does the question exclude repeats?

Comment: @DavisHerring See the last comment on Mad Lee's answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, try this:

```
import random
D=[]
M=[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]
for r in range(10):
    idx = random.randint(0, len(M) - 2)
    D.append((M[idx], M[idx+1]))
```

Comment: It will not give two adjacent pairs of elements @Mad Lee

Comment: This gives repeated pairs, D will not contain repeated pairs. @Mad Lee

Answer (score 0):

If your M is small and your adjacent pair should strictly be in the same order as M, first form the value pair list and then choose one from that list:

```
In [1]: M=[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]

In [2]: N = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(M[:-1], M[1:])]

In [3]: N
Out[3]:
[(2, 0),
 (0, 8),
 (8, 6),
 (6, 4),
 (4, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 4),
 (4, 6),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 6),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 89),
 (89, 12),
 (12, 23)]

In [4]: import random

In [5]: random.choice(N)
Out[5]: (2, 4)
```

If you want the list in a shuffled order and want 6 pairs:

```
In [3]: random.shuffle(N)

In [4]: N[:6]
Out[4]:
[(89, 12),
 (0, 8),
 (6, 4),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 0),
 (6, 5)]
```

Comment: `N = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(M[:-1], M[1:])]` --> `list(zip(M[:-1], M[1:]))`

Answer (score -1):

This appears to give the proper results. I did edit an above answer to get the proper results.

```
import random
D=[]
M=[2,0,8,6,4,0,1,2,4,6,5,6,5,89,12,23]
for r in range(10):
    try:

        idx = random.randint(0, len(M))
        D.append((M[idx], M[idx + 1]))
        print(D)
    except:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: If you want to edit an answer, do so rather than adding another to consider separately.

Comment: I am so very sorry. I am brand new to this site. Just trying to help. Thank you I will edit answers in the future.

Comment: No harm done—just remember you can propose edits even before you can comment!